# MSSQL Comparing rows same table

Tags: sql-server

Hi im looking to compare several rows and check if a certain condition is true/false.
The tables has several columns the ones im interested in are:

- Events.Badgeno
- Events.Name
- Events.Date
- Events.Time
- Events.Region_id
- Events.Data

The region ID can either be 1 or 2.

I want to check weather the same badgeno registers with a different region within a specified date/time difference say 10 mins. (Could be 10 mins before or 10 mins after).

I'm looking to show the records which don't have a record against the 2 regions.

As a further note it should only be within the first and last records of that badge per day.
Normally each record should have a region 1 and 2 record at the start and end. But there maybe multiple region 1's through out the day.

Any suggestions for the best method?

Id  Date    Time    Name    Badgeid Region

3385033 27/02/2014  08:16:11    FirstName Surname   5304    2

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work

```
SELECT e.Badgeno,e.Name, e.Date, e.Time,e.Region_id, e.Data
FROM events e
INNER JOIN events e1 ON e1.BadgeNo = e.BadgeNo AND e1.Region_id <> e.RegionId AND DATEDIFF(minutes,e1.date + e1.time,e.date + e.time) > -10 AND DATEDIFF(minutes,e1.date + e1.time,e.date + e.time) < 10
WHERE e1.Region_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

you should provide sample data.

> This Query is not complete,you can try something with
>   row_number/rank/dense, partition and check thus number column
>   generated .

```
select *,
row_number()over(partition by badgeno,regionno order by badge no)rn from table
where condition of date time
```